# Set Authorization header using PHP and curl

Tags: php, rest, curl

We're using Commission Junction's REST service, which requires we sent an API key in the `Authorization` header.

We set the header like this:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
  // set url, timeouts, encoding headers etc.
  CURLOPT_URL => 'https://....',
  // ...
));

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
  'Authorization: ' . CJ_API_KEY,
  'User-Agent: ' . OUR_USER_AGENT
));

$response = curl_exec($ch);
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
```

The problem is that the `Authorization` header isn't sent (we debugged this by using a local url and doing a `var_export($_SERVER)` which shows a `User-Agent` header is set, but not the `Authorization` header.)

If we change the header name to `X-Authorization`, it gets sent - but this hasn't helped us as the service specifically requires the `Authorization` header.

How do we get PHP + cURL to send an arbitrary `Authorization` header?

Comment: Why oh why is this not in the $_SERVER variable?! Incredible

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The `Authorization` header isn't included in PHP's `$_SERVER` variable.  To properly debug a request you should use `apache_request_headers()` which shows we were sending the `Authorization` header exactly as we wanted.

The problem then moved on to figuring out exactly what to put in the `Authorization` header given some pretty bad documentation.

Comment: How do I close this question as irrelevant now?

Comment: You don't need to close it.  It was a valid question and you answered it.  Someone else may find this information very useful one day.

Comment: I just found this useful... some two years lates.

Comment: I can send HTTP header these days: curl_setopt($apiCon, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Host: api.mixi-platform.com', 'Authorization: OAuth ' . $accessToken));

Answer (score 4):

When the header is set by the client, then the `Authorization`-header from the request is included in `$_SERVER` — not sure if this is something new, but it is now. HTTP-headers get prefixed in the `$_SERVER` array with `HTTP_` which may be something you previously overlooked.

Also, `apache_request_headers()` is a function which is only defined when you use Apache as a web server. So everyone with nginx etc. is left out.

### Demo

On the server-side:

```
<?php
// server.php
var_dump($_SERVER['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION']);
```

#### Test

Start a webserver (requires PHP 5.4):

```
$ php -S 0.0.0.0:31337 -t .
```

*Make sure server.php is in the current directory.*

Use cURL to test:

```
$ curl -H 'Authorization: FOO' http://0.0.0.0:31337/server.php
string(3) "FOO"
```

Works. :)