# Converting cURL command line to PHP

Tags: php, curl, command-line

This is the command line:

```
curl --silent --header "Authorization: MyLogin auth=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" "https://www.myweb.com/"
```

I this is what I have (tried all kinds of variations with the header)

```
    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.myweb.com");

    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array('Authorization: MyLogin','auth: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'));

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

    $output = curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close($ch);

    echo $output;
```

I think I am messing up the header part, any help will be much appreciated.  Thanks.

Added*  This is what I am actually working with

http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/articles/using_cURL.html#authenticating

I just rewrote it and now it works, this is what i have:

```
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Authorization: GoogleLogin auth=$authCode"));
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true); // for debugging the request
    //var_dump(curl_getinfo($ch,CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT)); //for debugging the request
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    echo $response;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the `Authorization` header should be sent all as one string, not as 2 header values.

Try this line instead:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Authorization: MyLogin auth: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'));
```

Comment: Yeah I have tried it that way, as well as with = instead of :, thanks though.  I am thinking I may be calling the wrong header type of call, though I don't know what else to use.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you could check the **CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER** and **CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST** false to prevent any SSL certificate like issues.... also whats the error code that you get like a 403 access forbidden... any information on the Error or a Verbose based log would be much useful... hope my suggestion helps someway...

Cheers!!

Comment: I gave those a try, still same.  This is the error, it just isn't validating though it works perfect at command line {
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "authError",
    "message": "Invalid Credentials",
    "locationType": "header",
    "location": "Authorization"
   }
  ],
  "code": 401,
  "message": "Invalid Credentials"
 }
}

Comment: @user1062332 guess you could check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1304974/set-authorization-header-using-php-and-curl) might prove useful in your case

Comment: Thanks but that didn't help me.  I have tried every combo of what is used in the command line version and it still doesn't work.